# SortableJS: можно ли выполнять сортировку не во время перетаскивания, а после него?

Tags: sortablejs

Использую библиотеку [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable?tab=readme-ov-file#readme) для создания списка с возможностью сортировки через drag'n'drop.

По-умолчанию сортировка происходит сразу же в процессе перетаскивания, то есть перетаскиваемый элемент сразу двигается вдоль списка за курсором. Возможно ли запретить это, а выполнять сортировку пост-фактум, то есть после наступления dragend?

```
new Sortable(list, {
     animation: 150,
     draggable: '.draggable-item',
     forceFallback: true,
     fallbackOnBody: true,
})
```